# How can i scroll with facebook browser?

Tags: facebook, browser, scroll

i have problem with facebook browser.. If i use chrome/mozilla... for view detail of product, everething is ok, but if I use facebook browser, or some customer use it from facebook advertisement, than the problem start. In detail of product is magic zoom (modul for zooming photos) and the customer can not scroll down. I mean bounce with finger from the photo to down...site example: (https://viamor.cz/snubni/kolekce-2019/product/417-model-2001)
Do you know, how can i solve it? Thank you.

Comment: I would reserve the magic zoom for your own website, and not use it with facebook.  Facebook probably has limitations on what you can do in their pages/browser anyway.